# How to do lock in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function called AddElementToDom() in javascript, it runs a loop over an array and adds elements 's to the Dom (many of them, it takes long time). the function is being called from different events. I want to make sure that every call to this function is waiting to the previous call to finish the function before starting another AddElementToDom. my Idea is doing lock() like in c#. but I couldn't find one in javascript. what is the best way to implement a lock ?

Comment: Look for "promise pattern" if you're working asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single-threaded so you don't have concurrency issues. Hence, no locks. Locks are meant to resolve concurrency problems.

You might still want *logic* though, to say "operation Foo shouldn't run until operation Bar is completed."  Like:

```
var operationBarIsCompleted = false;

function foo() {
    if(!operationBarIsCompleted) {
        return;
    }
// ...
}

function bar() {
    // ...
    operationBarIsCompleted = true;
}
```

But now I'm just writing programming logic for you.

However if this is event-driven then you need to learn to work with asynchronous code and callbacks.  I can't teach this over an SO answer; [plenty of resources on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+asynchronous+callback) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+asynchronous+callback).

Comment: But if the function is written like jquery Closures ?

Comment: @HaddarMacdasi see last two lines in my answer. Also try posting a more specific question.

Comment: I added "alert(1)" inside the function and I get 10 alerts one above the other, it shows that the function being  executed multiple times in parallel, all I need is for each execute to wait until the last one ended.